# Why am I allowed to make this substitution in the integral?

Tags: integration

I have the following integral equality given to me $$\int_0^xf'(z-t)dz = \int_{-t}^{x-t}f'(z)dz$$
and I'm wondering what is allowing us to make this change? Substitution doesn't immediately appear to resemble this right-hand integral.

Answer (score 3):

If $t$ is constant, then $d(z-t)=dz$, so we can substitute $u=z-t$. Can you see what happens after that?

Comment: Ah I see it now, thank you!

Comment: @McT Sure - no problem!

Answer (score 0):

I was almost done with this while the other answer was posted, but I figured i might as well post this. Using fundamental theorem of calculus:$$\int^x_0f'(z-t)dz=f(x-t)-f(-t)\\\int^{x-t}_{-t}f'(z)dz=f(x-t)-f(-t)$$